# Exporting and clipping soil layer downloaded from ISRIC

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, clip, soilgrids

How do I export and clip a soil layer downloaded from ISRIC?

I just downloaded a soil PH to ArcGIS, but I only need the 0-5cm mean layer, I found no place to export this layer to a raster/vector. And I only need the North American extent.

I am thinking 0-5 cm mean layer should be extracted first, then clipped to North America.

[image: !]

Comment: Please provide a link to the source dataset so people can understand what it is you have actually downloaded? From the screen shot looks like a WMS service, so nothing is downloaded?

Comment: What all options are seen when you right-click over the layer, like does the data-->export is not available?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean with "export"? Is your goal to obtain a raster file from tthe

Comment: Sorry I did not say clearly. I downloaded the PH layer from https://maps.isric.org/ Yes, it is a WMS service, what you mean nothing downloaded? I have to move this WMS PH layer to my own file? I can open this WMS service PH layer in Arcmap, but I cannot do anything such as export one of its data(soil pH 0-5cm). I wanna export soil PH 0-5 cm as a raster, yes.

Comment: From the server side the Getcabalities  document `https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0` indicates a queriable layer and without major problems.

For data download the recommended service is WCS (and not WMS)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot export from the WMS then they have disabled it, it is not downloadable.

Suggest you read the section *How can I access SoilGrids* in the [FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using QGIS instead of ARCGIS, if you used QGIS, you can choose each layer and export it by clicking the right mouse button, unchecking vrt box and using any vector layer as the extent to be exported using it as box